# Getting the returned values with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I can not return values with multiproccessing. Actually, I want to get these values in my main script that I want to do.

```
**plc_connect.py**

*Example functions*
def get_temp_humidity_value():
    with LogixDriver('xxxxxx') as plc:
        temp = plc.read('xxxx').value
        humidity = plc.read('xxxx').value
        result=[ temp,humidity]
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
   p2 = Process(target=get_temp_humidity_value)
   p2.start()
   p2.join()
```

```
**main.py**

import connect_plc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = connect_plc.get_plc_data()
    print(result)
```

```
**Output**

None
```

Answer (score 0):

ok in this part if you need both together :

```
def multi_threading(target, args =(), daemon=True):

    import multiprocessing
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=args)
    proc.daemon = daemon
    proc.start()
```

if you wanna to access to all of value you can return as a list and then you can read as many value in your list:

```
    result = [temp , humidity]
    return result
```

sth like this!

Comment: [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/oyofocagey.py) Stiil output is "None".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle 2 calculation at the same time but in a different thread
check this out:

```
def run_func_as_thread_multi_threading(target, args =(), daemon=True):
    """

    :type daemon: causes the thread to terminate when the main process 
    ends.
    """
    import multiprocessing
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=args)
    proc.daemon = daemon
    proc.start()
```

Comment: [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/oyofocagey.py) Stiil output is "None".